# Python Tkinter: Why is my if...elif statement not working with a StringVar()?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter, spyder

I know this code needs to be improved but first I can't figure out why sample_choice a tk.StringVar() seems to not be passed to my if...elif block. What I'm trying to do with the code is display certain labels based upon a selection in a Combobox which saves its current state in sample_choice. It seems like after the first execution of this function the program never loops back into the function even though it is called and in the mainloop and the if...elif block is never reached to take an action on a newly selected value in the Combobox. I think I'm missing something pretty basic here. If more information is needed please let me know and I will upload the class this function is apart of. Thanks in advance!

```py
def pin_interface(self):
    
        path = "Images\\Sample.png"
        sample_choice = tk.StringVar()
        samples = ("Sample A", "Sample B")
        pin_index = ("A1:", "A2:", "A3:", "A4:","B1:", "B2:", "B3:", "B4:")
 

        sample_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = path)
        img_label = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, image = sample_img)          
        img_label.image = sample_img
        img_label.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
        
        
        label_1 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = "Select a Sample:")
        label_1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        option_1 = ttk.Combobox(self.settings_subframe_2_1, textvariable = sample_choice, values = samples, width = len(samples[0])+1)
        option_1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
           
        pin_label_a1 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[0])
        pin_label_a2 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[1])
        pin_label_a3 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[2])
        pin_label_a4 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[3])
        
        pin_label_b1 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[4])
        pin_label_b2 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[5])
        pin_label_b3 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[6])
        pin_label_b4 = ttk.Label(self.settings_subframe_2_1, text = pin_index[7])
    
        
    
        if sample_choice.get() == samples[0]:
        

                pin_label_b1.grid_forget()
                
                pin_label_b2.grid_forget()
        
                pin_label_b3.grid_forget()
        
                pin_label_b4.grid_forget()
                    
                    
                pin_label_a1.grid(row = 3 , column = 0, sticky = "W")
                
                pin_label_a2.grid(row = 4 , column = 0, sticky = "W")
        
                pin_label_a3.grid(row = 3 , column = 1, sticky = "W")
        
                pin_label_a4.grid(row = 4 , column = 1, sticky = "W")
        
        
        elif sample_choice.get() == samples[1]:
                    
                pin_label_a1.grid_forget()
                
                pin_label_a2.grid_forget()
        
                pin_label_a3.grid_forget()
        
                pin_label_a4.grid_forget()
                
            
                pin_label_b1.grid(row = 3 , column = 0)
                
                pin_label_b2.grid(row = 4 , column = 0)
        
                pin_label_b3.grid(row = 3 , column = 1)
        
                pin_label_b4.grid(row = 4 , column = 1)
```

Comment: You are testing the value of your ComboBox about a millisecond after creating it.  It's *not physically possible* for the user to have made any selection yet.

Comment: Right, but doesn't this code get run in a loop using the mainloop method from the Tk class? My thinking was that a user makes a change and in the next loop that change will be picked up.

Comment: If this code was run in a loop, it would be creating a new Combobox and Labels each time.

Comment: If `pin_interface` is a function of a class, it will be called only upon explicitly calling it through an object of that class. `Mainloop` in tkinter tells Python to run the Tkinter event loop. This method listens for events, such as button clicks or keypresses, and blocks any code that comes after it from running until the window it's called on is closed. So, it is not like your `pin_interface` function will be called every millisecond, it will be called only when you actually call it.

Comment: To loop back in the if...elif block,  after user makes a selection in `Combobox`, you can add a `button`, which when clicked, will call function `pin_interface` (through the button `command`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not work because you check for the selection before the window is even displayed. You should check for the selection after the user changes the value of the Combobox.

In order to do so, you best bind the event of changes in the Combobox to a function that checks the values and takes action. I would suggest making the StringVar an attribute of your tkinter widget, so it can be accessed from all methods:

```
[...]
self. sample_choice = tk.StringVar() ## Make it an attribute of self

[...]
option_1 = ttk.Combobox(self.settings_subframe_2_1, textvariable = self.sample_choice, values = samples, width = len(samples[0])+1)
option_1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
option_1 .bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.check_value)
```

Then, you just need to move your complete if-block to a new method of self, called `.check_value()`:

```
def check_value(self):
    if self.sample_choice.get() == samples[0]:
         pin_label_b1.grid_forget()
         pin_label_b2.grid_forget()
    [...]
```

This method is now executed whenever you make changes to the selection of the combobox.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for your help!